# Bibtex on a webpage?

Tags: python, bibtex

Are there any python packages to parse a Bibtex file, and output the result using html/xhtml format, with a customizable styles?

Preferably, I would like to use python, otherwise what are the most used in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pybliographer](https://pybliographer.org/) (BibTeX for Python)
[Bibtexbrowser](http://www.monperrus.net/martin/bibtexbrowser/) (BibTeX for PHP)

Answer (score 3):

[Pybtex](http://pybtex.sourceforge.net) also exists, though I have not used it.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a package called [Bibliograf](https://launchpad.net/bibliograf) for ubuntu. 
It is a python script that outputs bibliography listings in HTML+CSS format.

Answer (score 1):

There are also services and tools to do this. Obviously, there is good old [bib2html](http://www.litech.org/~wkiri/bib2html/). If you'd rather just embed a code snippet using a service and not worry about installing anything, you can try: [bibbase.org](http://bibbase.org). (Disclaimer: I'm the author of bibbase.org.)

Comment: Is there a way to construct a URL so that bibbase can search for unions or intersections of keywords, or to use wild cards in keywords?

Comment: What is it that you would bibbase to search based on those keywords, i.e., which list/database? Do you mean the https://bibbase.org/network/keyword/biostatistics

Comment: Sorry, sent the previous comment too soon. You can pick a keyword and then filter further on it (intersect), e.g., https://bibbase.org/show?bib=http%3A%2F%2Fbibbase.org%2Fall%2Fkeyword%2Fbiostatistics&filter=keywords:strategy, but you cannot currently union.

Comment: Thanks Christian.  Unions or wildcards would be nice additions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Citeline](http://citeline.mit.edu/), which formats bibliographies nicely using the [SIMILE widgets](http://www.simile-widgets.org/)

Comment: 404 - looks like this project is dead and just some of the widget remain.